# forbidden ajax in cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am trying to make an Ajax request and I miss the 403 forbidden error so the state investigating is an access problem.
This is my code.

```
function EnviarInformacion(accion,objEvento){
    $fecha = $('txtFecha').val();
    $titulo = $('#txtTitulo').val();
    $hora = $('#txtHora').val();
    $color =$('#txtColor').val();

  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'CalendarioPlantillas', 'action' => 'agregar')); ?>',
      dataType: "json",
      data:{
        fecha:$fecha,
        titulo:$titulo,
        hora:$hora,
        color:$color
      },
      succes(msg){
        calendar.rerenderEvents()
          $("#ModalEventos").modal('toggle');
          $.notify('<?= __("Evento almacenado correctamente") ?>','success');
      },
      error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
        alert("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
      }
  });
```

}

And to allow the use of my action add I added the following code.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
 parent::beforeFilter($event);
 $this->Auth->allow(['agregar','delete']);
}
```

Comment: Array arguments are separated using a comma, not a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Use unlockedActions

```
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    $actions = ['agregar','delete'];
    if (in_array($this->request->getParam('action'), $actions)) {
        $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', $actions);
     }
}
```